# Хранимые процедуры MySQL в веб приложениях

Tags: mysql, mysqli, joomla3

Почитав топик по поводу хранимых процедур совместно с Joomla.
https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/stored-procedure-in-joomla

Обратил внимание на второй ответ.

Вопрос. Мне одному кажется этот ответ полным бредом?

Перевод ответа ниже.

> Не рекомендуется использовать хранимые процедуры в MySQL для веб-приложения. MySQL компилирует хранимые процедуры по требованию и удерживает их в кеше на основе соединения. Практически каждое веб-приложение (включенное Joomla) открывает новое соединение с каждым URL-адресом (открывайте соединение, обслуживайте страницу, кликайте ссылку, открывайте новое соединение, обслуживая страницу и т. Д.). Это означает, что каждая хранимая процедура, которую вы вызываете, будет скомпилирована один раз для каждого веб-запроса, обрабатываемого сервером. Накладные расходы могут быстро съесть все, что вы можете получить, если ваше приложение не будет сидеть там и повторять вызовы одной и той же хранимой процедуры при каждом запросе страницы.
>
> Хранимые процедуры MySQL могут быть полезны для того, что вызывается
>   многократно, прежде чем дать пользователю изменения, требующие
>   большего, но в значительной степени каждый запрос на веб-сервер
>   приведет к открытию нового соединения и повторной компиляции
>   процедуры.

Comment: не то что бы совсем бред. но не думаю, что время компиляции процедуры сильно отличается от времени компиляции обычных запросов которые будет выполнять клиент для получения тех же результатов, что дала ему процедура. Да и FastCGI и использование одного подключения для обработки многих запросов никто не отменял. правда надо конечно смотреть на сколько совместимо использвание fastcgi с движком джумлы

Comment: оно никак не совместимо. причем тут  FastCGI  и  php?

Comment: fastcgi это технология. И php может работать в режиме fastcgi. главное что бы приложение это понимало и не пыталось заново открывать соединение, умело нормально инициализировать все переменные без факта перезапуска скрипта

Comment: я всегда считал что хранимая прцедура компилируется 1 раз и сразу же прописывает план выполнения. а не компилируется при каждом вызове.

Comment: Странное утверждение. Кэш для соединения описан в документации для пользовательских функций, но не для хранимых процедур. Найти бы оригинал текста, на основе которого дан тот ответ...

Comment: ну в оракле например точно один раз копилится и все. А вот на счет MySQL не знаю.